# Select Option issue in IE-11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue in IE 11 for html select option.

I have Select list which loads multiple items. I am able to select an item from the list for the first time. when i try to move into next item by using touchpad,it's not moving to next item (when we move into next item, the selected item is highlighted in blue background color.instead of that, item is selected as brown highlighted color). If i use Keyboard, I am able to move into next item by using up/down arrow key.

Note: This works fine in other browsers.
Has anyone faced this issue.? please comment.

Much appreciated.

Thanks
Sivarajan

Comment: I encountered the same issue. There was a javascript error that was being thrown on IE11 that was preventing the select. Although, this error was being thrown on Chrome, it was more forgiving. After fixing the javascript multiple selects worked fine.

Comment: thats great... Can you share the code which helped you to fix.

Comment: The problem was that there was a global function that was checking to see if there was a mouse click event.The error was that it was unable to get the target's parent. The reason this occurred was because the target was null. So modified the code to first check if the target was null, if not null then access it's parent. Hope this helps